# Redux createStore, compose function - How is this code working?

Tags: node.js, redux

I'm trying to understand the working of Redux functions, I'm able to understand how we create the Redux store and apply middleware.

While creating Redux store, we pass the rootReducers, preloadedState, storeEnhancer.

But in this code, I'm not able to understand how the resultant enhancer from compose function is given as input to the createStore function.

```
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import rootReducers from './reducers'
let finalCreateStore = compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk),
    window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f
)(createStore)

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
    return finalCreateStore(rootReducers, initialState)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Both `applyMiddleware` and `window.devToolsExtension` functions return a "store enhancer", meaning a function of the form `createStore => createStore`.
Each one of them expects to get a createStore function and returns a new one, which adds some functionality to the newly created store.

The code could be written without compose as:

```
let finalCreateStore = createStore;

const devToolsStoreEnhancer = window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f;
finalCreateStore = devToolsStoreEnhancer(finalCreateStore);

const middlewareStoreEnhancer = applyMiddleware(thunk);
finalCreateStore = middlewareStoreEnhancer(finalCreateStore);
```

Notice that `compose` applies the layers from last to first, so the order is reversed: https://redux.js.org/api/compose

Now `finalCreateStore` is a function with a similar signature to the original `createStore`, but contains two layers of enhancers above it.
You can now create your store with a code like this:

```
const store = finalCreateStore(rootReducer, initialState);
```

When you call `finalCreateStore(...)` those layers create the store for you and add middleware and devtools support to it.

Hope it helps :)